# How to update RBAC database for Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using DbManager for RBAC. What is a good strategy for updating the RBAC database tables once they have been created? Is there a good extension that can be used to view the roles and rules and update them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RBAC with DbManager, (Yii2 Adevanced Template ) i use

- In `auth_permission` table i use  `TYPE_PERMISSION`  for assign the permission (what i check for grant access) and  `TYPE_ROLE` for  create a application role.
- `auth_assignment` table for assign the role to the user.
- `auth_item_child` table for grouping the permission to a role.

For manage this a i have create a few views with gii,  based on the normal RBAC table

I Hope this is useful for you

Comment: Good idea.  I will use Gii to generate the CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

The native authManager is quite powerfull!

Here follows some examples.

Get the authManager instance

```
    $auth = \Yii::$app->authManager;
```

Create a Permission

```
    $permission = $auth->createPermission('/service-helper/*');
    $permission->description = 'Post';
    $auth->add($permission);
```

And add the Permission to a Role

```
    $userRole = $auth->getRole('editor');
    $auth->addChild($userRole, $permission);
```

See the [Yii2 Authorization Guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md#role-based-access-control-rbac-) that's quite exaustive.